# Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/style' in production firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I built a Next js app for which am trying to add some css.
Tried using the built in styled-jsx css lib . All works fine in local.

Now, when I upload the same in firebase hosting and try SSR using firebase functions . I get this error .

**Question is  : If styled jsx is part of next js then why am seeing this error . That too only in production**

Using next js 6+ .

I know i can always add styled jsx as a dependency , but trying to understand why  its not working since its supposed to be built in to next js already.

Thanks in Advance!

This is my package.json content :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "firebase": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5",
    "next": "^6.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.2",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.18.6",
    "prettier": "^1.13.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  }
```

**Error :**

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/style'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/next/server/bundles/pages/mystatus.js:245:18)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 51b5f67292a9fe79adac:21:0)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/next/server/bundles/pages/mystatus.js:101:75)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 51b5f67292a9fe79adac:21:0)
at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/user_code/next/server/bundles/pages/mystatus.js:89:18)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 51b5f67292a9fe79adac:21:0) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', sourceMapsApplied:
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: updated error stack

Comment: Did you make sure that `next` is added as a dependency not only in your `App` folder, but also in the `functions` folder's `package.json` ?